# jquery: can you do an ajax request in $(window).unload()?

Tags: php, jquery

I am absolutely terrible at logging my hours.

So my idea is to have a browser shortcut that i open when i am starting work.

Then when i am finished close it.

This will then to an ajax request to a php script that will update my hours for me.

To do this.

Can i do an ajax request in `$(window).unload()`?
or will the browser close before this completes?
and, will the php script on the other end run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run an **synchronous** AJAX request (`async: false` in [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)) in `window.onbeforeunload`, but an *asynchronous* one (the default) will most likely be cancelled before it completes.  Note that this isn't the same as the `unload` event, which is strictly for variable cleanup  (though `beforeunload` is arguably for the same purpose).

I tend to recommend *against* doing this, as it delays the user's experience waiting on your AJAX request to complete, when they just want the next page.

Comment: But for a situation as i have described in my question would you recommend this, or would you say, log automatically every 10 minutes?

Comment: @Hailwood - I'd say that's a good alternative, whatever fidelity you need with the minutes would work.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you make a synchronous AJAX request, the browser will not wait for the request to finish before closing.